# How to separate Excel cell text based on days and months?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

I have cell value with `115y300d` which needs to be move to separate cell, however in few cell I have data like `10h30m`, so it's mixed text.

What I want to do is value before "y" should go in Year Column "d" in Days, similar for h = hours and M in Minutes. Since it is not in similar format, I'm not able to do text to columns and other functions, and need your help.

[image: Data.excel]

Answer (score 0):

You could use find() to do things like so:

```
=if(iferror(find("y",A2,1)>0,0),left(A2,find("y",A2,1)-1,"")
```

which will put the value before y into the cell or set it to blank.
Expand the idea to find d & y etc

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=DROP(WRAPROWS(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(BYROW(A1:A5,LAMBDA(a,IF(RIGHT(a)="d",a&"hm","yd"&a)))),,{"y","d","h","m"},,""),4),-1)
```

If you hit `CONCAT()` limits, you can also do this by row (dragging):

```
=TEXTSPLIT(IF(RIGHT(A1)="d",A1&"hm","yd"&A1),{"y","d","h","m"},,,"")
```